# Javascript json callback

Tags: javascript, json, callback

what does

```
script.setAttribute('src', '/json?callback=loadJsonPhotos');
```

JavaScript code mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a little snippet of code to set the `src` (source) attribute of a Javascript include tag to `/json?callback=loadJsonPhotos`. Once that line of code runs, the browser will fetch the data from that URL and execute the script that returns. The data that script returns will be wrapped in a function like so:

```
loadJsonPhotos({data: "blah"});
```

All you need to do to use that data is write a function called loadJsonPhotos that will be called once the data has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the `src` attribute of the html for `script` to `/json?callback=loadJsonPhotos`

Answer (score 0):

This script is equivalent to write the following html code:

```
<script src="/json?callback=loadJsonPhotos"></script>
```